# Ubuntu Web Apps Application Indicator not going away

Tags: indicator

By this I'm talking about the little Mail icon in the top right corner. I accidentally allowed webapps integration for Reddit but I subsequently removed Reddit from the list of allowed domains

```
gsettings set com.canonical.unity.webapps allowed-domains []
```

and I removed the following packages

```
unity-webapps-reddit
unity-webapps-common
unity-webapps-service
```

but I still have this

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The package you're looking for if you want to get rid of this, is `evolution-indicator`. Remove that, and it should remove the mail icon.

i.e. `sudo apt-get remove evolution-indicator`.

The others you refer to simply use that package as an interface to display their notifications, they don't put the icon there by themselves.

Comment: When I try that, I get:
E: Unable to locate package evolution-indicator.